# Question about poissrnd, the poisson generator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, poisson

I got a problem when using poissrnd. 
If n is a series of numbers. In theory the variance of poisson(k×n) should be k times the variance of poisson(n). 
However, I got k∧2 instead of k. My code is attached. 
Can anyone point out what is wrong with my understanding and explain why it doesn't work as theory. Please help me, thanks![image]

Comment: Please don't attach a screenshot, just copy and paste the code in a editable format.

Answer (score 1):

`poissrnd(a)` generates a Poisson random value with `a` as mean. By the way you define `a`, your output is a series of random values that all have a different mean. As you know, the variance of the Poisson distribution is equal to its mean. This means that you are computing the variance of a series of values that do not represent the Poisson distribution with a single parameter (they more closely resemble values with a uniform distribution!).

Instead, generate an `a` by

```matlab
a = 10000 + zeros(1,10000);
```